# OCaml - Is it possible to define external (system) dependencies in dune?

Tags: ocaml, dependency-management, ocaml-dune

I made an OCaml library that relies on an external/system package (namely *libnauty2-dev*).

Since I would like my library to be installed via opam I looked for a way to specify the external lib as a dependency.
So far I have found that .opam files can specify such dependencies with

```
depexts: [ "libnauty2" ]
```

And here is my question:
Is there a way to specify my dependency in a dune-project file so that generated .opam file will contain the same dependency ?

Answer (score 2):

The dune language doesn't directly support this part of opam file generation, but you can create a `<packagename>.opam.template` file with your `depexts` rules and dune will paste the contents of that file at the end of the generated .opam file.